# halachic status of a "Promise"

Tags: halacha, words, nedarim-shevuot

If I promise something by saying "I Promise..... to do something". What status does that have. Does it have the same status of a Neder? Or maybe a promise has no significance in halachah and therefore I don't have to give any credence to it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does saying "I promise..." constitute any halachic obligation?](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44725/does-saying-i-promise-constitute-any-halachic-obligation)

Comment: It seems much more likely to constitute a Shevua than a Neder. What sort of Korban is referred to by "promise"?

Comment: See also http://www.dinonline.org/2013/06/20/keeping-your-word-a-moral-obligation/, http://businesshalacha.com/en/newsletter/breaking-promise

Comment: @Shokhet While it might be a duplicate (status in Halacha) that question does not appear to have a full answer. It could be considered as the question rewritten to get a better answer.

Comment: @sabbahillel Ok, so it's a "the question rewritten to get a better answer" which means it still gets closed as a dupe...

Answer (score 0):

The first mishna in Nedarim states that כנויים "equivalent terms" for neder, charamos, or shevua are treated as if they are actually a neder, cherem, or shevuah. This would imply that "I promise" would be treated like the alternative terms given in Aramaic.The Art Scroll gemoro notes on the first mishnah point out that a neder is a Chovat Cheftzah (apply to the object), while a shevuah is a Chovat Gavrah (apply to the person).

However, as applied to the meaning. the words "I promise" would seem to be the modern equivalent of saying "I am making a neder" while "I promise Hashem" (or some other reference to Hashem) is like "I swear" and is meant to be a shevuah.