# Must one fulfill a promise to another? What if circumstances change the initial reasoning behind the proposal?

Tags: halacha, nedarim-shevuot, gifts

If one states that they will do something to another person (e.g "I'll give you my favorite necklace"), and then that person no longer wants to fulfil the "promise" due to unforeseen circumstances, is that forbidden? What if the statement was only written and not verbally uttered?

Comment: ~simular Mishnah Nedarim 66a

Comment: related: [Does saying “I promise…” constitute any halachic obligation?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/44725/11501)

Answer (score 5):

It appears indeed one should keep his promises in the context of a small gift. The Rambam writes ([MT Mechira 7:9](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1363912/jewish/Mechirah-Chapter-Seven.htm)) (based on the gemara in [Baba Metzia 49a](https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Metzia.49a.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

> **Similarly, if a person promised to give a colleague a gift and failed to do so, he is considered to be faithless. When does the above
>   apply? With regard to a small gift, because the recipient will depend
>   on the promise that he was given.** With regard to a large gift, by
>   contrast, the giver is not considered to be faithless if he retracts,
>   because the recipient does not believe that he will give him these
>   articles until he transfers ownership through a formal kinyan.

The Shulchan Aruch codifies this in [CM 204:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Choshen_Mishpat.204.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

dinonline ([here](http://dinonline.org/2013/06/20/keeping-your-word-a-moral-obligation/)) writes

> The precise definition of which gift is considered small and which is
>   large depends on the circumstances of the giver: For a poor individual
>   a gift of $50 may be large, whereas for a millionaire a gift of $1,000
>   can be considered small.

See [there](http://dinonline.org/2013/06/20/keeping-your-word-a-moral-obligation/) at length, particularly the end section "Keeping One’s Word in Transactions".

As always, treat the above as sources, but don't make real-life decisions without speaking to your rav. There might be mitigating factors one way or another that will impact the final ruling

Comment: FWIW I’m not convinced that this Gemara extends to the more general case beyond the OP’s question, i.e. if one has to fulfill *any* promise. After all, the Gemara makes several references which limit it strictly to monetary matters (application of Mi Shepara, source from balanced scales, etc.).

Comment: @DonielF it certainly does **not** extend to business transactions (the case here is a gift) so I agree with you one cannot extrapolate from it to other situations

Comment: What are you talking about? The Gemara explicitly discusses הין צדק, that one shouldn’t go against one’s word in business and cannot do so if there’s been money put down. A gift, discussed in that Gemara, is just a special case of a business transaction.

Comment: There is a difference between a large gift and a business transaction. Compare MT Mechira 7:8 and 7:9. I understand your first comment to mean that the halacha on gifts and transactions is not exactly the same - and I meant to write that I agree - but maybe I misunderstood you

Comment: Correct, it’s not exactly the same, but certainly if I say I’m going to, I dunno, walk five blocks today without anything classifying it as a Neder, nothing is binding me to that.

Comment: Does this apply if the indented recipient did something that would make the giver change their mind? for example they are no longer on speaking terms.

Comment: @YosefGavriel as I wrote in the end, for specifics like this, one would need to ask a rav to balance the obligation vs. new facts that might have occured